# Stop jQuery animation when a modal layer (or tab changes) appear top of the animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jQuery animation plugin using sequence of images.. I need to `pause` the animation when a `modal layer` opens up or a tab changes on top of the animation. Can't figure out where to tie up the animation stop..

Here is what am doing..

http://designs.phases.dk/flip/

The animation starts once all the images loaded.. now if you click on the link "Open Popup" the modal layer appears..  but the animation still continues.. trying to find a way to stop it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just trigger the "pause" link's click event to pause the animation.

```
$('.fancybox').click(function(){
      $('.pause').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just other version - on model load - use  parent.$("#pause").trigger('click');